# How to create a new table into a database on android studio?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

im working on an android project using an sqlite database, after create the database i realized that i need a new table so i try to add it among the others on my SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
  BaseDeDatos.execSQL("create table viaje(id_viaje integer primary key, tiempo integer, revs integer,  esfzosub integer, esfzobaj integer)");
```

But when i  run the app and press the button my aplication just crashes and gave me the following message:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sfzosub (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE viaje SET sfzosub=?,sfzobaj=?,id_viaje=?,id_categoria=? WHERE codigo=1

i see that the problem is that changes on the database arent made i tried to restart android studio, rebuild the app and i still have the same problem so, how can i do changes to my database?

Comment: If the change to database is not to a deployed app then simply remove app from device and reinstall.  If a deployed app then you'll have to issue alter statements on upgrade.  The columns are slightly different e.g. esfzosub vs sfzosub - so perhaps that's the changes you're trying to effect.

Comment: Thanks bro, i was so focused on the DB that i didnt realize that mistake, in fact i was trying to insert into  sfzosub insted of esfzosub due to a confusion with a variable on my code, really thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big question now is **where** do you call the creation of the new table? If you do this in

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
```

Your code won't be executed, as the database already exists!

To properly handle that, add it to

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(YOUR_STRING);
```

And then change the version of your Database to a higher number. When you restart the app it will see a new version and run `onUpgrade`.